# Оптимизация кода python

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть вот такой скрипт:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import os

pages = []

for x in range(4615):
    pages.append(requests.get('https://link.com/companies/' + str(x)))

for r in pages:
    html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

    for el in html.select('.show-company'):

        title = el.select('.panel-body > .right-part > .right-panel')
        id = title[0].get('data-id')
        name = title[0].get('data-name')
        description = title[0].get('data-description')
        url = title[0].get('data-website-url')

        os.mkdir(id)

        n = open(id +'/name.txt', 'w')
        n.write(name)
        n.close()

        d = open(id +'/description.txt', 'w')
        d.write(description)
        d.close()

        u = open(id +'/url.txt', 'w')
        u.write(url)
        u.close()
```

Если поставить 
`for x in range(20):` вместо `for x in range(4615):`, то скрипт начнёт выполняться через секунд 7-10, если же поставить `4615`, то не понятно, начнёт ли он выполняться вообще. Как я понимаю, изначально в цикле открываются все страницы, а потом следующий цикл начинает уже их обрабатывать. Пробовал сам менять код, но всё время выпадало вот в эту ошибку: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Можно ли сделать так, что бы скрипт открывал одну страницу, брал из неё информацию, закрывал и переходил к следующей?

Comment: Ну как бы должно быть очевидно как исправить указанную ошибку.

Comment: Должно быть, наверное, но явно не со стажем в 1 день...

Comment: это самые элементарнейшие азы языка, без которых у вас разве что хелло ворлд будет работать. Тут и полдня достаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно :

```
import os

import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

for x in range(4615):
    r = requests.get('https://link.com/companies/' + str(x))
    html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser') 
    for el in html.select('.show-company'):
        title = el.select('.panel-body > .right-part > .right-panel') 
        id = title[0].get('data-id') 
        name = title[0].get('data-name')
        description = title[0].get('data-description') 
        url = title[0].get('data-website-url')
        os.mkdir(id)
        with open(id +'/name.txt', 'w') as n, open(id +'/description.txt', 'w') as d, open(id +'/url.txt', 'w') as u:
            n.write(name)
            d.write(description)
            u.write(url)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Только лишняя скобка вот вот тут: `str(x)))`

Comment: @Apelsin2020 подправил код

Comment: Выполнение прекращается после 10 проходов цикла, т.е. создаётся 10 папок, но потом скрипт закрывается и нужно запускать заново, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @Apelsin2020 ошибку не выдает никакую?

Comment: Нет, просто закрывается

Comment: @Apelsin2020 не знаю, честно говоря

Comment: А нет, вот что выдаёт: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "das.py", line 19, in <module>
    d.write(description)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1841-1842: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Apelsin2020 это из-за "непонятных" символов на вебстранице

Comment: Я так и понял, добавил encoding='utf8', надеюсь поможет